# How to speed up T-SQL like search with two Nvarchar(max) columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've narrowed the query to this:

```
select * FROM items where accountid=4755 and (itemId like N'%9976%' or [description] like N'%9976%' or fulldescription like N'%9976%' )
```

Both 'Description' and 'FullDescription' have been scaled down from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(4000).

Seems that still I cannot build index on that because it is too big (can't go any lower). Also, if I remove either 'Description' or 'FullDescription' it works fast, so the slowness is the compound effect. Also, this query without the LIKE conditions contains only 1,000 rows in a relatively small database.

Comment: Do you search like: `WHERE col LIKE '%phrase%'`?

Comment: I've just added a snapshot of the code

Comment: Use Full Text Search

Comment: Do you have an index on `Extent1.AccountId`?

Comment: Does it have to be varchar(max)?

Comment: If it doesn't have to be varchar(max) you could find the max(len(column)) and then alter column to varchar(i.e. max len)...and then put an index.

Comment: Index on accountId didn't help much.. any other ideas?

Comment: All  your LIKEs seem to search from the beginning... How big is the data you are searching in? How long is the LIKE-string you use to search? If you cannot shorten your columns to put a normal index to them you could think about an indexed search table with smaller columns and fill them with a trigger.

Comment: How large is the table ?  Are there any rules regarding the @P_linq variables in regards to length ?

Comment: The search phrase is pretty short

Comment: Did you try adding a smaller column to the table, which will hold the first X number of characters of the large column (which is why the length of the variables is important). Then you can add this column to the indexes and to the where clause with '='.

Comment: I still believe that `Full Text Search` would be best. But if that is not an option then I'd go with Amir's solution. Probably not every word contained within these `nvarchar(max)` will be searched for. Try to get the search words into a seperate column. Example: if you search always for a number then get all the numbers from these `nvarchar(max)` extracted into a seperate column and index this new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did end up with something similar to what Amir suggested here..  Since 98% of the data is pretty short we've created another two columns nvarchar(450) which meets the 900 bytes limit, then created indexes for them.

We're hosted on Azure and time is pressing, so we didn't look into free text search. We also came across Azure Search service which may be a fit for this, but that requires a time consuming POC.

Thanks everyone.